Uncaught TypeError: import_mongoose.default.connect is not a function | HONO | Typescript
I am trying to build an app using hono, I want to use mongoose but on running the server it shows service core:user:backend: Uncaught TypeError: import_mongoose.default.connect is not a function
import { Hono } from "hono";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const app = new Hono();

app.get("/", (c) => {
  return c.text("Hello Hono!");
});
mongoose
  .connect(
    ""
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected To DB");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
export default app;


Help me with this
I tried installing @types/mongoose also but still the problem persists

Replace:
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
With:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

reference: Understanding esModuleInterop in tsconfig file

